# How to reverse order of stacked bars in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I have this data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(variable = c("var1", "var1", "var1", "var1", "var2", 
                            "var2", "var2", "var2", "var3", "var3", "var3", "var3", "var1", 
                            "var1", "var1", "var1", "var2", "var2", "var2", "var2", "var3", 
                            "var3", "var3"), percentage = c(12.565445026178, 18.848167539267, 
                                                            42.4083769633508, 26.1780104712042, 3.57142857142857, 11.2244897959184, 
                                                            45.9183673469388, 39.2857142857143, 4.59183673469388, 10.2040816326531, 
                                                            57.1428571428571, 28.0612244897959, 3.03030303030303, 12.1212121212121, 
                                                            39.3939393939394, 45.4545454545455, 2.94117647058824, 5.88235294117647, 
                                                            38.2352941176471, 52.9411764705882, 17.6470588235294, 29.4117647058824, 
                                                            52.9411764705882), score = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                   3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                   4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), group = c("group1", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "group2"), label = c(6.282722513089, 21.9895287958115, 52.6178010471204, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          86.9109947643979, 1.78571428571429, 9.18367346938776, 37.7551020408163, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          80.3571428571429, 2.29591836734694, 9.69387755102041, 43.3673469387755, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          85.969387755102, 1.51515151515152, 9.09090909090909, 34.8484848484848, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          77.2727272727273, 1.47058823529412, 5.88235294117647, 27.9411764705882, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          73.5294117647059, 8.82352941176471, 32.3529411764706, 73.5294117647059
                                                                                                                                                                     ), percentage2 = c("13%", "19%", "42%", "26%", "4%", "11%", "46%", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "39%", "5%", "10%", "57%", "28%", "3%", "12%", "39%", "45%", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "3%", "6%", "38%", "53%", "18%", "29%", "53%")), .Names = c("variable", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "percentage", "score", "group", "label", "percentage2"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -23L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I try to make a faceted stacked bar chart with this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = percentage, fill = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  geom_text(aes(y=label,label=percentage2), color='grey25', size=2) +    
  facet_wrap(~ group,ncol=2)+
  coord_flip()
```

As you can see, the labels are not on the right spots in the bars. I need a reverse order of the bars. I know it sounds a bit like a duplicate question, like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134596/reverse-fill-order-of-stacked-bars-with-faceting), but when I try that solution I get this error:

**Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: order**

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))`?

Comment: thanks, that worked! (and my apologies, I completely missed that duplicate)

Comment: No worries, there's a bunch of them but most are outdated or have poor answers.

Answer (score 0):

Several points to make:

1. `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')` is now replaced by `geom_col()`
2. You should not change the `y` aesthetic
3. Use the `position` argument with `position_stack(vjust = 0.5)`

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = percentage, fill = score)) + 
    geom_col(position = 'stack')+
    geom_text(aes(label = percentage2), 
              position = position_stack(vjust = .5), 
              color='grey25', 
              size=2) +    
    facet_wrap(~ group,ncol=2) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]